# C*-algebras and unitary elements.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

We say that an element $u$ in a $C^{*}$-algebra is unitary if $u^{*} =u^{-1}$. Furthermore we assume $u$ is normal as well And because of that $$\sigma(u^{-1}) = \{ \lambda^{-1} : \lambda \in \sigma(u)\} = \{ \overline{\lambda} : \lambda \in \sigma(u) \}. $$

To me that inequality does not seem obvious, where does it come from?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sigma(u)$?

Comment: spectrum of u..

Comment: If $0\neq r\in\mathbb{C}$, then $u-r$ is invertible iff $u^{-1}-r^{-1}=-r^{-1}u^{-1}(u-r)$ is invertible. Therefore, $\sigma(u^{-1})^c=(\{r^{-1}: r\in\sigma(u)\})^c$. Similarly, $u-r$ is invertible, iff $u^*-\overline{r}=(u-r)^*$ is invertible. This last if because if $v$ is an inverse for $u-r$ then $e=v(u-r)$ and taking $^*$ we get $e=e^*=(v(u-r))^*=(u-r)^*v^*=(u^*-\overline{r})v^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those equalities have nothing to do with normality.

In any case, the equality $u^*=u^{-1}$ implies that $u$ is normal, as any element commutes with its inverse by definition.

Note first that since $u$ is invertible we may assume $\lambda\ne0$.

The equality $$ (u-\lambda) ^{-1}=-u^{-1}\lambda^{-1}\,(u^{-1}-\lambda^{-1})$$ shows that $$\sigma(u^{-1}) =\{\lambda^{-1}:\ \lambda\in\sigma (u) \}. $$ Similarly, the equality $$(u^*-\overline\lambda) ^{-1}=[(u-\lambda)^{-1}]^*$$ implies $$\sigma(u^{*}) =\{\overline\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma (u) \}. $$